# Android AsyncTask in another AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to run an AsyncTask in another AsyncTask with this code:

```
   protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    InetAddress inetAddress;
    try {
        while (true) {
            inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");
            mSocket = new Socket(inetAddress, 4444);

            SocketData data = new SocketData();


            GetPacket pack = new GetPacket();
            AsyncTask<SocketData, Integer, Integer> running = pack.execute(data);
```

but have an error : 
***Method must be called from the main thread android current inferred thread is worker***

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Why can't you just do everything you need to in one `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in the `onProgressUpdate` this method is running on the MainThread

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    publishProgress(data);
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(SocketData... data) {
    GetPacket pack = new GetPacket();
    AsyncTask<SocketData, Integer, Integer> running = pack.execute(data[0]);
}
```